# Problemas com string no printf

Tags: c, string, printf

Fiz esse código simples e ao tentar gerar o printf da variavél do tipo char o console não trás as informações, porém, caso não faça o print da variavel do tipo char o console mostra tudo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char nome;
    float sal,bonus,totsal;

    printf ("Entre com o nome do funcionario: ");
    scanf ("%s",&nome);
    printf ("\nEntre com o salario bruto do funcionario: ");
    scanf ("%f",&sal);
    
    bonus = (sal * 30) / 100;
    
    totsal = sal + bonus;
    
    printf ("Funcionario: ");
    printf ("%s ",nome);
    printf ("\nSalario com bonus %2.f",totsal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf ("%s ",&nome);`

Answer (score 2):

Na linha:

```
char nome;
```

E na linha:

```
scanf ("%s",&nome);
```

Você está tentando ler um `char[]` mas usar `scanf` com `"%c"` vai resultar apenas na leitura do primeiro caractere.

Neste caso, troque a linha onde declara a variável nome para:

```
// Troque 20 pelo tamanho que preferir comportar ou use malloc() para alocar a memória necessária. 
// Não se esqueça de chamar free() depois caso opte por usar malloc.
char nome[20];
```

E na linha onde resgata a entrada do usuário:

```
scanf ("%s", nome);
```

Pois ao trocar `char` para `char[]`, estará passando um ponteiro para uma região em memória, que já é um endereço. Ou seja, não há a necessidade de usar `&` novamente. Ao final, se executarmos o programa com as alterações teremos:

```
Entre com o nome do funcionario: João

Entre com o salario bruto do funcionario: 2000
Funcionario: João 
Salario com bonus 2600
```